# Русские буквы в имени файла. TZipFile

Tags: delphi, archive, delphi-xe8

Хочу разархивировать файл(*.zip). В нем содержатся файлы имена которых на русском.
Вот такая конструкция

```
procedure TWorkThread.ExctractZip(aArchFile: string; aPath: string);
var
  zZip: TZipFile;
begin
  zZip := TZipFile.Create;
  try
    zZip.ExtractZipFile(aArchFile, aPath);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(zZip);
  end;
end;
```

В итоге после разархивации имена этих файлов превращаются в кракозябру `Çéè«¡Γα«½∞ αÑßΓ«αá¡δ.pdf`

Как это побороть?

Comment: А содержимое файлов при этом нормальное, без искажений? Delphi до-юникодная?

Comment: Да, без искажений.

Comment: А чем создавался архив и какая версия delphi?

Comment: Не могу знать чем и как создавался архив. Он просто есть. Delphi XE8 / Win 7

Comment: Какая локаль на компьютере (русская, английская)?

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, формат ZIP не слишком строго стандартизирован (к примеру, Unicode был официально стандартизирован в только в 2007 году - в спецификации PKWARE 6.3.2). Проблема даже не только в стандарте, сколько в бесчисленном количестве программ, которые сохраняют имена как им вздумается - что, в общем-то, не удивительно при такой спецификации.

В частности, существует несколько вариантов хранения имён файлов с символами, выходящими за рамки ASCII:

1. ANSI
2. OEM
3. CP437 (DOS Latin US)
4. UTF-8
5. UTF-8 с флагом
6. Дополнительное (extra) поле $7075 - стандарт PKWARE/Info-ZIP
7. Дополнительное (extra) поле - я забыл числовой код, от другой программы

Ужасная мешанина. Что хуже всего - часто нет никакого способа определить метод хранения имён, кроме ручного указания человеком (первые четыре способа из списка выше программно неразличимы).

Поиграйтесь с [флагом UTF8Support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.UTF8Support): если поможет - хорошо, если нет - надо или искать другой распаковщик, или другой упаковщик.

Comment: кракозябы в вопросе указывают, что архив был создан, используя OEM codepage (cp866), а распакован, используя ([стандартную для zip](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)) cp437 кодировку: `'Çéè«¡Γα«½∞ αÑßΓ«αá¡δ.pdf'.encode('cp437').decode('cp866') == 'АВКонтроль рестораны.pdf'`. Если нет необходимости поддерживать древние доисторические zip-распаковщики, то следует при создании архива кодировать имена файлов используя bit 11 и utf-8 кодировку (вариант UTF-8 c флагом в ответе).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно изменить стандартный модуль zip.pas.
Проверено на Delphi 10.2.

```
function TZipFile.TBytesToString(B: TBytes): string;
var
  E: TEncoding;
begin
  if CyrillicSupport then //условие, нужна ли поддержка кириллицы, можно убрать
    E := TEncoding.GetEncoding(866)
  else
  if FUTF8Support then
    E := TEncoding.GetEncoding(65001)
  else
    E := TEncoding.GetEncoding(437);

  try
    Result := E.GetString(B);
  finally
    E.Free;
  end;
end;

function TZipFile.StringToTBytes(S: string): TBytes;
var
  E: TEncoding;
begin
  if CyrillicSupport then //условие, нужна ли поддержка кириллицы, можно убрать
    E := TEncoding.GetEncoding(866)
  else
  if FUTF8Support then
    E := TEncoding.GetEncoding(65001)
  else
    E := TEncoding.GetEncoding(437);
  try
    Result := E.GetBytes(S);
  finally
    E.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не специалист по дельфи, но вы можете попробовать стандартные `decode-encode` с разными кодировками. Составляете заранее словарик из русских букв и в каждой попытке определить кодировку побуквенно прогоняете полученное название через словарик. Как только нашли совпадение - вуаля. Это если проблемы с названием. Также, например, в питоне есть библиотека `chardet`, которая определяет кодировку самого файла, а не его названия.

Comment: К сожалению, это не ответ на вопрос (не решение проблемы), а комментарий.

Comment: Комментарий подразумевает ответ на него. Моё решение существует независимо от реакции и, главное, решает проблему. Вы получили кракозябру и, сравнив её со словарём, отбросили и перешли к следующей кодировке. Мне кажется, что это, наоборот, ответ, а никак не комментарий. Вы более опытный участник сообщества, поэтому если будете настаивать, я ответ удалю или перенесу в комментарии.

Comment: Настаивать не буду, просто к сведению